# What's the equivalent of MdiWindowListItem when using a DockPanelWorkspace?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cab

We have a composite application with a DockPanelWorkspace as its main user interface area.  Above this sits a MenuStrip with a window menu set as its MdiWindowListItem.  Unfortunately, as I feared, the window menu isn't populated with the open views.

Is there an equivalent in CAB that will populate a menu with a list of the open views in a workspace?  If not, how should I go about implementing that feature?

Answer (score 0):

MdiWindowListItem is automatically populated with items added as MdiChild. You have to develop custom logic for docked window, handling the following .

- Adding menu item to the window menu (set as MdiWindowListItem)
- Removing the menu item when the related window is closed
- EventHandler for selecting the window when the menu is clicked
- I am not familiar with DockPanelWorkspace.

  - So logic of selecting the window has to be sorted.
  - Changes of DockState like the window changes to MDIChild